# Start Web design with combination of html css javascript jquery and php

Tags: web

I know the basics of: html, css, javascript, jquery, and php. Now I want to start making interactive websites. Is there any book or tutorial that starts with all of them being used?

Comment: You may want to google it first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could start with a common framework, start altering things and build up to developing that framework from scratch. For  some php examples, Wordpress is a good option, codeigniter and cake are also good.

If you have a project in mind, you could just start from scratch and as you come along problems that you do not understand how to get around, just google the issue. It will probably bring you back here though.

You could start doing some of the tutorials at codeschool.com or teamtreehouse.com. I am sure there are tons more too!

Answer (score 0):

My recomendation is to you begin to study ways to build an API with PHP beside a mysql or mongo, of course using an framework like laravel or cake. After that you need to integrate this API with a view and i recommend that you study a framework like angular or react. However, see the google search below that may helps you a lot.

https://www.google.com.br/search?sourceid=chrome-psyapi2&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8&q=angular%20laravel&oq=angular%20laravel&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.6098j0j7